# Exslt date:add($date, 'P1M') in Umbraco, just adds 30 days

Tags: date, umbraco, exslt

```
<xsl:value-of select="date:add('2010-10-01', 'P1M')"/><br/>
<xsl:value-of select="date:add('2010-07-01', 'P1M')"/><br/>
<xsl:value-of select="date:add('2010-02-01', 'P1M')"/><br/>
<xsl:value-of select="date:add('2010-09-01', 'P1M')"/>
```

...gives:

2010-10-31T00:00:00

2010-07-31T00:00:00

2010-03-03T00:00:00

2010-10-01T00:00:00

This is not useful. Is there actually a way of adding a month short of splitting the date myself?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, should have done a bit more digging, but ah well, may this post will help someone else :o)

If you use the Umbraco library function instead of the Exslt it works fine:

```
<xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:DateAdd('2010-10-01', 'm', 1)"/>
```

...gives:

2010-11-01T00:00:00

(and the other moths including Feb work the same)